# Parsing SNS event Containing S3 events in Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I required multiple lambdas to subscribe to s3 bucket events, this is not supported so the idea is to introduce the SNS instead.

The flow will be S3Event -> SNS -> (X Number of LAMBDA consumers)

The setup and architecture is find, and the Lambda is being triggered correctly with the Event type

`SNSEvent` with the `ILambdaContext. This is fine.

My problem is when trying to parse the S3 events from the SNSEvent Message.

```
foreach (var record in snsEvent.Records)
{
    var snsRecord = record.Sns;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(snsRecord.Message))
    {
      logger.Error("Message is empty", record);
      throw new Exception("Message is empty");
    }

  // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  var s3Event = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<S3Event>(snsRecord.Message);
  logger.Info($"{s3Event.Records.FirstOrDefault()?.S3.Object.Key}", snsEvent);

  await ProcessParsedEvent(s3Event, context);
}
```

The exception is not throw for an empty `snsRecord.Message` however the cloudwatch is a generic object reference error. However I can't seem to see it.

I suspected there were more than 1 event of a different type which maybe be causing issues with the deserializer, so i added :

`var records = snsEvent.Records.Where(x => x.EventSource.ToLowerInvariant() == "aws:s3");`

However the same results.. Is there something specific I need to do for deserializing the s3 events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the Deserialiazer's property case sensitivity.

The solution in my case was to add the `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` in the `JsonSerializerOptions` set to true.

From here the SNS message (which contains the s3 event message in JSON format, lower case, is able to deserialize correctly.

```
  var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions
  {
      PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
  };

  var s3 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<S3Event>(s3Json, deserializeSettings);
```